# Objective C ORM

Tags: objective-c, ios, orm

I am new to Objective C. In previous practice I accustomed to use ORM-like frameworks to access the database.

Could anyone please recommend any decent ORM framework for Objective C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good database library/ORM for cocoa development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310479/good-database-library-orm-for-cocoa-development)

Comment: Not sure if that is a duplicate as the OP is asking for cocoa-touch and not cocoa. This entirely depends on the fact that the provided answer actually work exactly the same way on cocoa-touch (iOS).

Comment: Also, that question explicitly states that Core Data cannot be used in their case, due to the need to interact with MySQL and the like. If you are just looking for an ORM and using SQLite as your database is fine for you, then don't even bother looking at anything beyond Core Data on iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of alternatives out there, but in my opinion, nothing is better than Apple's Core Data. It is easy to use and implement, and is incredibly well documented (as everything that comes from Apple).

One excellent resource to learn Core Data quickly and use it right away is Paul Hegarty's CS193P videos available on iTunes U, which you can download using the following link:

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=480479762

Comment: Except it's not technically an ORM.

Comment: No offence meant and I hope none taken, although clearly you have to comment on it.  Either way, fine... I'll keep your peace.  However Core Data is not an ORM and should probably not be used as such. Whether or not a lot of people really want an ORM when they ask for one is another discussion entirely.

Comment: CoreData is NOT ORM, also not allowing to perform complex queries would make you need to populate much more data to achieve the same as SQLite (I know the OP is asking for ORM, but in resume you will use SQlite allways)

Comment: I am not saying in any point of my answer that Core Data is ORM! Since the user said "ORM-like" in the question, I thought Core Data could be useful to him.

Answer (score 15):

The following are for SQLite on iOS:

- [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)
- [chibi-ORM](http://code.google.com/p/chibiorm/)
- [sqlitepersistentobjects](http://code.google.com/p/sqlitepersistentobjects/)

Comment: This is the correct answer to the Op's question.  Core Data is not an ORM, it cannot be used to wrap an existing database in an Object Relational Manager.  Core Data datastores are not usable except through Core Data.

Comment: FMDB isn't either, its a (great) light wrapper around raw SQLite3 API calls. You use plain old SQL queries to do everything you need with it.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: DBAccess has now been replaced by the open source ORM Shark.

We have recently released a free to distribute and use ORM for Objective-c / iOS called DBAccess, which can be downloaded from http://db-access.org/, it has taken several years to develop and has now been deployed within many applications.

The documentation is fairly basic, but is slowly getting created/updated and we welcome community feedback and suggestions.

There is also a roadmap available to detail what features are going to be released in the up-coming releases.

It may not be for everyone, but I hope our effort will help some in the community.

*NOTE*, I have been alerted to the fact that it is bad form to promote your own products in a forum such as this, but I just wanted to add that I am only posting this in answer to the OP because I feel it does bring something useful to the table and I sincerely hope it will prove helpful to some people, even if it's not for everyone.

UPDATE: DBAccess has now been replaced by the open source ORM Shark. It is API compatible, and is available on github. http://sharkorm.com and https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm

Thanks Adrian_H

Comment: I can't speak for the rest of the community, but I felt this answer directly addressed the OP's question and was informative.  The fact that you're the author shouldn't take anything away from that.

Comment: At this moment it is not open source,  although that is a source of constant negotiation within the company.

Comment: @Nav DBAccess has now been replaced by the open source ORM Shark, it is the follow up project and is API compatible drop in replacement.

Answer (score 1):

SQPersist is a Objective-C Persistence framework wrapper around SQLite based on FMDB :
[Visit Github page](https://github.com/christopherney/SQPersist)

Answer (score 0):

I totally recommend [Realm](http://realm.io/). IMHO it is an excellent choice for its simplicity and performance.