# ORM for SQLite in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, orm

I am trying to convert a C# application we had developed to an iPad application. As we developed the app with Entity framework, I am looking for a counterpart for iOS.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8545631/749973), there are several ORM libraries for SQLite in iOS:

- [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)
- [chibi-ORM](http://code.google.com/p/chibiorm/)
- [sqlitepersistentobjects](http://code.google.com/p/sqlitepersistentobjects/)

But after reading each of the web sites, I still can't decide which package to use. Can anybody who has experience with one of them tell me advantages/disadvantages of the packages?

Comment: Did you look into Core Data? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: if you are going to redesign the database I agree with @SB., you should try Core Data, but if you plan to use the same database (or database structure) from the libraries that you mention I have worked with fmdb with pretty good results, it is fast and easy to use (I haven't tested the other ones)

Comment: @tkanzakic Thanks for your great tip. Redesigning database is the last thing we want to do as we already have existing database from current C# application.

Comment: @SB I looked into it but many people say that it is not ORM so I kind of stayed away from it so far.

Comment: I would NOT recommend CoreData, it's painful to discover you cannot make complex queries with it. We have lost several days of work after achieving this.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin try this https://github.com/LakithaRav/OLCOrm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've dealt with the limited number of ORMs for quite some time, and I finally did something to improve the limited options available. I've written an ORM and released it under a BSD license for everyone to use. It's posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/nschilling/StorageLayer).

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: DBAccess has now been replaced by the open source ORM Shark.

We have recently released a free to distribute and use ORM for Objective-c / iOS called DBAccess, which can be downloaded from http://db-access.org/, it has taken several years to develop and has now been deployed within many applications.

It may not be for everyone, but I hope our effort will help some in the community.

*NOTE*, I have been alerted to the fact that it is bad form to promote your own products in a forum such as this, but I just wanted to add that I am only posting this in answer to the OP because I feel it does bring something useful to the table and I sincerely hope it will prove helpful to some people, even if it's not for everyone.

UPDATE: DBAccess has now been replaced by the open source ORM Shark.  It is API compatible, and is available on github.  http://sharkorm.com and https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm

Thanks Adrian_H

Comment: What's the license for your project? I'm a bit leery to try it without knowing what I'm getting myself into :).

Comment: Hi Max, we are going for the MIT license. It seemed the easiest and most applicable for our wishes.

Comment: Hi Adrian, is there any guide for upgrading table? Like adding, renaming, removing field from table?

Comment: Hi Tek, the database is modelled from the classes, so if you add a new property to a class it automatically gets added to the table, and the same with removing a property.  Renames will create a new column and remove the old one.  If you send me your email address I can email you a category that exposes the upgrade mechanism which is not yet finished, which will enable you to migrate data from deleted columns.

Comment: @Adrian_H I know this thread is a bit old but I'm wondering if this can be used for FTS (Full Text Searching).... If yes, how can I get a guide?

Comment: @ragingprodigy, there is no support for SQLite's implementation of FTS in DBAccess atm, although it sounds like a good idea and if you email us we will keep you posted on progress.  In theory it should be something nice and quick to implement.  We would like to discuss how we would go about implementation with people to make sure we understand the requirements.  It would be a nice, differentiating, feature.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to convert an c# app to iOS is Xamarin i think, there is a library [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) , works good.